# NodeJS and Express JS: 404 while trying to get to the router

Tags: node.js, forms, express, http-status-code-404

I am working on a project where I need to upload a text. But for some reason, the control is not moving to the router. Also, only this particular router function isnt working, and others routing functions in the router work

Here is my relevant code

This is the form to collect the data

```
    <div class="content ui segment" id="two">
        <form  method="POST" action = "/documents/uploadDoc">
          <h2>Name</h2>
          <br>
          <input class='button' type="text" id="myName" name="name">
          <input type="submit" name = "Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

The router code in documents.js :

```
router.post("/uploadDoc",function(req,res,next){
  console.log("Uploading");
  res.redirect("/documents");
});
```

App.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var dbSetup = require('./db_setup');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var bucket = require('./firebase_storage');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var courseRouter = require('./routes/course');
var documentsRouter = require('./routes/documents');
var classroomRouter = require('./routes/classroom');
var apiRouter = require('./routes/api');

const e = require('express');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// set user
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  res.locals.user = null;
  if(user) {
    var users = firebase.database().ref('/users');
    users.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      for(var rno in data) {
        var em = data[rno].email;
        if(em.localeCompare(user.email) == 0) {
          res.locals.user = data[rno];
        }
      }
    });
    res.locals.userEmail = user;
  }
  res.locals.url = process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_URL;
    next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/course', courseRouter);
app.use('/documents', documentsRouter);
app.use('/classroom', classroomRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);





// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error.jade');
});



module.exports = app;
```

On clicking the submit button, I get the 404 error, nor is "uploading" being printed in the console. Please help

Comment: Do you have the `Uploading` in the console.log ?

Comment: check ```documentsRouter ``` is exported.

Comment: Please don't use `var` any more.  Use `let` or `const`.  Pretty much anything you're assigning from `require()` should be `const`.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted VSCode, and though it does'nt make sense, it somehow worked. If you are facing the same issue, I suggest just restarting the software.

Answer (score -1):

your nodejs need to accept multipart/form-data to process your post request or you need to convert your file into base64 to send it as json param

here is an example for multipart/form-data

you can use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#readme) to accomplish that.

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: './public/data/uploads/' })
app.post('/stats', upload.single('uploaded_file'), function (req, res) {
   // req.file is the name of your file in the form above, here 'uploaded_file'
   // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
   console.log(req.file, req.body)
});
```

dont forget to change the file name for you to get on upload.single('yourFileName') ex:

```
<form action="/stats" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="uploaded_file">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of speakers" name="nspeakers">
    <input type="submit" value="Get me the stats!" class="btn btn-default">            
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why does the OP need `multipart/form-data`?  The form they show is one simple text field.  There's no need for `mutli-part` for that.  Besides, this issue wouldn't lead to a 404 anyway, it would lead to `req.body` not being parsed, but the desired route still hit.